# Does Ruby/Rails require more unit testing than say a PHP app?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I don't find the unit testing push in the PHP market like I see/read in the ruby/rails arena.

Could one just as easily NOT unit test in ruby/rails as in php, or is ruby just too bendable and breakable that it "more" recommended to test in ruby than in php?

Meaning there are large code bases like vBulletin, and from what I can tell, they don't unit test.

I hope you understand what I am asking here, not the pros/cons of testing, or whether one should test or not, but rather, does one language need to be tested more than another? maybe its easy to write buggy code, or break during refactoring etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tl;dr PHP/vBulletin/Mambo started before TDD went mainstream

PHP allows the same mistakes to be made as Ruby does. In Java/C# the compiler will complain sometimes if you do something odd at compile-time, PHP/Ruby will do that only on run-time. So if you were to compare Ruby with Java, I *might* have replied that I see a little more necessity to write unit-tests for PHP/Ruby. Still I consider unit-testing important no matter what the language you use.

**On your findings:** vBulletin (v3 development started in Dec 2002) and Mambo is nearly as old as jUnit (2000). Unit-testing (according what I can find) had its rise around the year 2000. SimpleTest/PHPUnit emerged in 2003/2004. So the devs of Mambo/vBulletin didn't use TDD back then. The structure of the written code won't have made it easy to add tests later on.

Not to dishonor any PHP developers, PHP was pretty overrun by script-kiddies, pseudo-programmers, and beginners (me included). Everybody started from scratch, wrote his/her own CMS. The reference app were some snippets found around the web. I assume that a large chunk of the PHP dev community will never have heard of unit-testing or have understood what it's good for.

Ruby was hyped much later (approx. 2007) than PHP (approx. 2000) was. It comes bundled with a lot of philosophy ("Whats good/readable/beautiful code?", "How should coding be done?"). Writing tests is somewhat a part of this philosophy.

Most books on Ruby contain a section on unit-testing, explaining why it's good and necessary. Also Rails generates a set of (empty) tests for you automatically. You are encouraged to write tests all the time - it's hard not to.

Comment: "You are encouraged to write tests all the time" It's a coding-maturity thing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you dont see as much automated unit and functional testing in PHP because the community has not embraced it - though that is changing. Its not that any language requires more or less testing its more about development methodologies and the tools the developers using that language are familiar with as well as cost of implementing something (in this case the tests).

With Rails unit and functional tests are easy. Theres a whole framework integrated for it... with scaffolding if i recall correctly. This greatly decreases the cost and knowledge level required to test an application in this fashion. Many times in PHP if you want to do this you have integrate PHPUnit, Lime, SimpleTest, etc.. yourself. With the rise for frameworks like Symfony, Zend, CI, and Cake the barriers in PHP are being lowered too assuming the development team uses a framework such as these.

Comment: well I believe dynamic languages need more tests than statically typed languages, don't you agree? (generally speaking)

Comment: Kind of... It depends on the project and more importantly the development and management team. In a dynamic language you can get away with some types of mistakes and yet all the expected functionality will still work because while its technically wrong, the interpreter changes that float to an int for you, or doesnt care that youre using an array instead of the entity that implements ArrayAccess. Some developers/managers/clients just dont care about this. As long as it works today and is on budget, they will often settle and even push for "good enough".

Comment: Also another point to be made is that most testing frameworks are built around OOP. If a project is still based on adhoc procedural code hacked together then implementing some sort of automated testing because incredibly difficult.

Comment: Yes, the important point is that Rails makes testing easy, so this removes a learning curve that you find in other languages, motivating more people to do it.  I knew 3 bright programmers in Java who wanted to test in JUnit, but could not get it to work in a short amount of time, so they did not write tests.  They wanted to put aside some time some day to get it working, but never really did.  The days become months, the months become years ... I'm pretty sure they're still not testing.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby is no more bendable, or breakable, than other languages because a programmer is free to do stupid things in Ruby just as they are in PHP, Java, or C.

Some programming environments (IDEs) do precompile-runs and check for syntax errors in the code, but if the developer has cast things wrong, or turned off warnings or error notices, they'll still be in a position to shoot their foot off. It's not the language's fault they did stupid things. It was a lack of discipline, or experience or forethought on the developer's part, not the language, that led to the code that caused the problem.

When I wrote in C I enabled all errors and set warnings to their highest severity. My code compiled without errors and I had a high degree of confidence that the code was good. At the same time I checked all my memory-allocations to make sure I got a value back, checked my return codes from system calls, etc., because I cared that my code ran right and was clean. I'd receive code from people who turned off warnings because they didn't like the stream of messages and it would fail, and reviewing the code showed it was full of ignored return codes and didn't check memory allocations. Similar to what Forest Gump said, "Sloppy is as sloppy does."

I've worked closely with some very talented PHP developers, and their code was every bit as clean as mine or a good developer in any language. I've also worked with very talented and experienced developers who wrote garbage, again, because they didn't care to write code that was maintainable and safe.

So, while some might want to point a finger and say a particular language isn't as good as another because the language fails too often, it comes down to the person with their hands on the keyboard. Leave the language out of it.

Testing, whether it's unit or integration, or whatever, is just one more step in the programming process that helps ensure good quality. Testing seems to require 2x the code as you'd have if you didn't test, but the automated component of testing is an incredible safety-net that can't be appreciated until you've had it catch errors after code changes, that would have broken an app badly.

About six months ago I started working regularly with some code written by a non-programmer. He's very talented at what he does but he needed a senior developer to team-program with him and show him why things are done a certain way. One of the first things I did with him was introduce him to the testing safety-net. He had some test code for incidental things but nothing that tested the actual behavior of the program. Once he saw it in action he was a believer, and now writes his tests as he goes. It's an awesome thing to see. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such a thing that one language requires more testing then the other ( they all require testing , writen tests or human tests or customer tests , all software get's tested at some point , tough it should get tested before hitting the market ).

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much that ruby **requires** it so much as it **supports** it so much better, and is part of the general philosophy and best practices that surround ruby, whereas php quickly got overrun by a lot of, well, amateurs.